# webpack 1 sourcemaps not showing es6

Tags: webpack

I am using Webpack 1 with babel6 and devServer and am trying to display the es6 source in Chrome/Safari, So far I only get to see the generated es5 code. Here is my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
}
```

and the webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var path = require('path');

config = {

  entry: {
    admin_index: [
      'babel-polyfill',
      './app/bundles/admin/index-entry.js'
    ],
  },

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../app/assets/javascripts/dist/'),
    filename: '[name]-bundle.js',
  },

  module: {
    cache: true,
    loaders: [
      { 
        test: /\.jsx?$/, 
        // loader: 'babel', 
        loader: 'happypack/loader',
        exclude: /node_modules|bower_modules/,
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, "app/bundles"),
        ],
        query: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
        }
      },
    ]
  },

  resolve:{
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
    modulesDirectories: ["node_modules"],
  },
  devtool: 'eval-source-map',
  plugins:[
    new HappyPack({
      loaders: [ 'babel?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react&presets[]=stage-0'],
      threads: 8,
    })
  ],

  watchOptions: {
    ignored: /node_modules/
  },

}
module.exports = config
```

I inlcuded a screenshot of the Chrome Resources tab's source

[image]

package.json

```
    {
      "name": "client",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha './app/**/*.spec.js' --compilers js:babel-register --recursive --require testSetup.js",
        "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch",
        "start": "NODE_ENV=dev node server.js"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.7.4",
        "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
        "babel-plugin-react-hot": "^1.0.4",
        "babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.18.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
        "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
        "babel-register": "^6.7.2",
        "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
        "enzyme": "^2.2.0",
        "eslint": "^2.6.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.0.1",
        "expect": "^1.16.0",
        "happypack": "^2.1.1",
        "jsdom": "^8.2.0",
        "mocha": "^2.4.5",
        "mocha-jsdom": "^1.1.0",
        "node-sass": "^3.4.2",
        "npm-check-updates": "^2.8.9",
        "npm-install-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "react-addons-perf": "^15.1.0",
        "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.1.0",
        "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.6",
        "react-render-visualizer": "^0.2.2",
        "redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
        "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.1",
        "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.11",
        "sinon": "^1.17.3",
        "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
        "webpack": "^1.13.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.3.0",
        "why-did-you-update": "0.0.8"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "Faker": "^0.7.2",
        "aphrodite": "^1.1.0",
        "axios": "^0.12.0",
        "classnames": "^2.2.5",
        "color": "^0.11.3",
        "counterpart": "^0.17.4",
        "cuid": "^1.3.8",
        "damals": "^0.9.4",
        "delay": "^1.3.1",
        "draft-js": "^0.7.0",
        "draft-js-export-html": "^0.3.0",
        "fecha": "^2.1.0",
        "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
        "halogen": "^0.2.0",
        "history": "^2.0.1",
        "humanize-plus": "^1.8.2",
        "intl": "^1.1.0",
        "lodash": "^4.13.1",
        "memoizee": "^0.3.10",
        "normalizr": "^2.1.0",
        "pluralize": "^3.0.0",
        "query-string": "^4.2.2",
        "query-string-parser": "^0.1.4",
        "react": "^15.1.0",
        "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.1.0",
        "react-dnd": "^2.1.4",
        "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.1.2",
        "react-dom": "^15.1.0",
        "react-dropzone": "^3.4.0",
        "react-functional": "^1.2.0",
        "react-grid-layout": "^0.13.0",
        "react-modal": "^1.4.0",
        "react-player": "^0.12.0",
        "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
        "react-router": "^3.0.0-beta.1",
        "react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
        "react-rte": "^0.5.0",
        "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.2",
        "react-stateless": "^0.2.1",
        "redux": "^3.5.2",
        "redux-crud": "^1.0.0",
        "redux-form": "^5.2.5",
        "redux-saga": "^0.14.2",
        "reselect": "^2.2.1",
        "seamless-immutable": "^5.1.1",
        "url-loader": "^0.5.7"
      }
    }
```

Can anyone spot anything that I might have had wrong in the config that prevents me from seeing the es6 in the chrome source tab?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of happy-pack are you using? Have you tried specifying `sourceMap: true` in the HappyPack plugin config? (e.g. after `threads: 8,`, put `sourceMap: true`)

Comment: @Nathan, I am using happy pack 2.1.1, I've also pasted the entire package.json to see if anyone could shed light on this.

Comment: You're transpiling your code down a version when building the bundle. Why would the ES6 version then be available. Maybe I'm missing something...